# Package validation Error while loading data from SQL server to flat file using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am trying to load data from an SQL server to a text file using OLE DB Connection. I am facing the below error message. Could someone help in resolving this?
[image]

OLEDB connection is already details
[image]

Comment: Could you please try recreating the oledb connection manager and reconfiguring the source with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OLEDB source does not have connection defined. You need to define new connection, as given below:

[image: OLEDB source connection]

Comment: Hi @venkatarama, Connection is already defined..but still, it's throwing the same error. For your reference image is attached in the original post